# how can i know the URI or full path from a bluetooth received file? Android SDK

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, share

i´m developing an android app that sends by bluetooth one picture to other android phone using ACTION_SEND intent (with chooser).

The other phone is receiving the file ok, but i want automatize my app to get this file when download is finished and open it in my screen.

by the moment i only got a notification in receiver phone notification bar. but i don´t know how to get this file and open.

Bluetooth path is changing dependig on android phone model, so i can not send the name and try to open in a fixed directory (already tested).

so i need know how to get the uri from notification bar, or get the real bluetooth folder for each model (this way i can send filename by bluetooth also).

thanks in advance.